# NotImplementedError(dtype) while using numba class method

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, numba

I'm using numpy 1.8.x and numba. I have a function called `train`, which has the following definition:

```
@autojit 
def train_function( X, y, H):
```

and it returns a 3D numpy array.

I then have a class, which calls this function, like so:

```
class GentleBoostC(object):
# different methods including init
# and now the train function
def train(self, X, y, H):
     self.g_per_round = train_function(X,y,H)
```

I then instantiate the class and use it to train an object.

```
# initiate the variables X_train, y_train and boosting_rounds
gentlebooster = gbc.GentleBoostC() # gbc has already been imported
gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,boosting_rounds)
```

But then I get this error:

```
    gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,boosting_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\app\Documents\Python Scripts\gentleboost_c_class_jit_v7_nolimit.py", line 299, in train
    self.g_per_round = train_function(self,X, y, H)  
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 152, in typeof_pyval
    dtype = numpy_support.from_dtype(val.dtype)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\numpy_support.py", line 61, in from_dtype
    raise NotImplementedError(dtype)
NotImplementedError: object
```

What's going wrong here?

### Edit

Looking at the documentation, it says:

> **exception NotImplementedError**
>
> This exception is derived from `RuntimeError`. In user defined base classes, 
>   abstract methods should raise this exception when they
>   require derived classes to override the method.

How would this translate to my case?

### Edit

More details on how I'm calling the train function:

```
#img_hogs and sample_labels have already been populated above, both are numpy arrays
X_train = np.array(img_hogs)
y_train = np.array(sample_labels)
boosting_rounds = 7

gentlebooster = gbc.GentleBoostC()
gentlebooster.train(X_train,y_train,boosting_rounds)
```

Comment: What are the dtypes of X_train and y_train? They seem to be not supported by the @autojit decorator.

Comment: X_train is a 2D float numpy array, and y_train is a 1D int numpy array.

Comment: Well, it appears numba receives a dtype of object, so double check on that.

Comment: I just edited the question to show how I'm really calling the train function. Both arrays are numpy arrays as far as I can see. Where else do you suggest I check? Is this an issue in calling the function, or do you think it's possible that there's something going on inside the train function that's problematic? But I've already deduced it's only when I call the function that there's a problem - because I commented out all the train function's inner code, except for one print statement, and made it not return anything, and I still got this error.

Comment: I've realized where the issue is - although I don't know how to fix it. If I reduce the arguments to the integer (boosting_rounds) alone, and redefine the function signature to take in only an integer, then it doesn't crash. So the problem is in passing the numpy arrays.

Comment: Okay so this is the issue... https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/506. And this is correct, my array X_train is a numpy array of objects. I'm not too familiar with Github, but doesn't the linked page show that the bug has been fixed?

Comment: I've posted a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709307/modify-raising-the-exception-notimplementederrordtype-in-numpy-support-py

Comment: That's one use-case of `NotImplementedError`, but more generally, it means that the functionality you are trying to use is not implemented (in this case, it looks like numba doesn't have support to jit `dtype=object`).

Comment: In general, machine learning libraries and classifiers don't accept `object` as input; your feature pipeline has to break it down to integers/ floats/ categoricals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My array `X_train` was a numpy array of objects, and [numba does not support that](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/506).

@Korem was right!
I was actually loading the `img_hogs` variable from a file like this:

```
img_hogs = np.array(pickle.load(file("C:\\PATH_TO_FILE")), dtype=object)
```

I just kept overlooking that. 
When I finally just removed the dtype=object bit, it worked!